# OpenSSL: Get the name of a hash algorithm by EVP_MD*

Tags: openssl

For logging I'm trying to find a way of getting the name of a hash algorithm by the `EVP_MD*` object. 
But I could not find a suitable answer anywhere.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on my own:

```
EVP_MD* pMD = EVP_sha256();

const char *mdalgSn = OBJ_nid2sn(pMD->pkey_type);
const char *mdalgLn = OBJ_nid2ln(pMD->pkey_type);

printf("ShortName: %s\n", mdalgSn);
printf("LongName: %s\n", mdalgLn);

//ShortName: RSA-SHA256
//LongName: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

Comment: As the versions creep on, they tend to render the structs more and more opaque.  For future-proofing, you might prefer `EVP_MD_name(pMD)` and `OBJ_nid2ln(EVP_MD_pkey_type(pMD))`